# Logical error of random value

Tags: c#, winforms, random

i created a win-form with an ability to generate a number with 3 labels(`label1`,`label2`,`label4`) and a `textbox` that will be storage and then validate its value when ever the button is pressed. my problem is that the `label4` didn't raise its own value when ever i answer it correctly.
with this code

```
int num = 0;
string temp;
        if (textBox1.Text == ans.ToString())
        {
            num++;
            temp = "Correct Answers " + num;


            int a = rr.Next(4), b = rr.Next(4);
            ans = a + b;
            label1.Text = a.ToString();
            label2.Text = b.ToString();          

            label4.Text = temp;
            textBox1.Focus();
            textBox1.SelectAll();

        }
```

Comment: When you step through this code, at what point does the observed behavior deviate from the expected behavior?  What are the runtime values when that happens?

Comment: Looks like you're resetting `num` every time

Comment: `num` keeps going out of scope, and you keep re-declaring it every time you execute the presumed event handler.  Perhaps you should declare it as a field or something.

Comment: i get the logic :) thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does `label4` never increase its own value, or does it never increase it more than the first time?  Because the latter of those two options is exactly what you're doing.  Look at the steps in your logic:

```
int num = 0;
string temp;
//...
num++;
temp = "Correct Answers " + num;
//...
label4.Text = temp;
```

No matter how many times you answer correctly, `label4` can *only* ever display:

```
"Correct Answers 1"
```

Because you *always* initialize `num` to `0`, increment it to `1`, and display it.  Where do you track how many answers have been given in total?

You'll need some integer value in a higher scope to track that.  Where you place it depends on the lifespans of your objects.  For example, if the object in which this logic exists persists across multiple answers (that is, if the same instance is always in memory and it's not destroyed and re-created), then you can add a class-level member to hold that value.  Something like this:

```
private int TotalCorrectAnswers { get; set; }
```

Then your code would use that value instead of instantiating a new one each time:

```
string temp;
//...
TotalCorrectAnswers++;
temp = "Correct Answers " + TotalCorrectAnswers;
//...
label4.Text = temp;
```

Other options could include storing the value in a static field to persist across object life cycles, a database to persist across application life cycles, etc.  It depends on how your application is structured.

Comment: oh i see so the correct method is that i need to put num = 0 to my public class not on my On click button so the value num never return to 0 ?; well thank you :) it really helps and for those who think my  question is a stupid well thank you. the point of the site is to help not to POINT OUT that your stupid ~_~.

Comment: @TabunJong: Um... ok.  From what I can see everybody here was trying to help you.  So... ya.

Answer (score 2):

So when you provide an answer to the math problem, the highest your Label4 that indicates correct answers counts is 1?  You aren't by chance defining the variable num within your click event handler are you?  In this case every time you got an answer correct it would increment num from zero to one, incorrect would show no change, but then your next correct answer would again increment from zero to one.